# Channel:mychannel received discovery error:access denied for role `member`

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I am trying to understand correlation of policies (`org`, `application` & `channel`) with `identities`, `MSP` and `NodeOUs` in complete process flow of hyperledger fabric. I am sharing my understanding, please correct me if I am wrong.

1. Presently, hf support 4 `NodeOUs`, and identities classification is enabled from `registerEnroll.sh` in `test-network` example. Also it supports 5 roles of identities `orderer`, `peer`, `admin`, `client` and `member`.
2. System channel policies, Org policies, application channel policies, consortium are defined in `configxtx/configtx.yaml` along with their capabilities.
3. Example of a org policy, application policy, and channel policy is given below:

```
        ##### Org Policy #####
        Name: Org1MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Org1MSP

        MSPDir: ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.peer', 'Org1MSP.client', 'Org1MSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.client', 'Org1MSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.peer')"


        ##### Application Policy #####
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "ANY Readers"
            Writers:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "ANY Writers"
            Admins:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
            LifecycleEndorsement:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
            Endorsement:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"


       ##### Channel Policy #####
           Policies:
            # Who may invoke the 'Deliver' API
            Readers:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "ANY Readers"
            # Who may invoke the 'Broadcast' API
            Writers:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "ANY Writers"
            # By default, who may modify elements at this config level
            Admins:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
```

My usecase is, create a identity with role as `member` using `signingIdentity` of `admin` and that `member` should be able to evaluate or submit transaction to chaincode, I tried following things to achieve this:

1. Added `'Org1MSP.member'` in `Readers` and `Writers` policy of the organisation in `configtx.yaml`
2. Ran `enrollAdmin.js`, fresh wallet got created.
3. Next, in `registerUser.js`, I changed `role` from `client` to `member` in function call of `ca.register` to create identity of a `member` rather than a `client`.
4. Now, when I ran `query.js`, it throws following error:

```
2020-05-22T09:28:40.219Z - error: [DiscoveryService]: send[mychannel] - Channel:mychannel received discovery error:access denied
Failed to evaluate transaction: Error: DiscoveryService: mychannel error: access denied
```

Further debug logs from the peer when it's validating identity.

```
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-05-22 09:28:40.217 UTC [policies] SignatureSetToValidIdentities -> DEBU 4de3 signature for identity 0 validated
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-05-22 09:28:40.217 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 4de4 0xc0034b0b50 gate 1590139720217279088 evaluation starts
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-05-22 09:28:40.217 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 4de5 0xc0034b0b50 signed by 0 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-05-22 09:28:40.217 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 4de6 0xc0034b0b50 processing identity 0 - &{Org1MSP 1635f57eaf46859c66528c1528475f51feac49aa83b3393c0bdc35e50e046f39}
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-05-22 09:28:40.217 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 4de7 0xc0034b0b50 identity 0 does not satisfy principal: The identity is not valid under this MSP [Org1MSP]: could not validate identity's OUs: the identity must be a client, a peer, an orderer or an admin identity to be valid, not a combination of them. OUs: [member(BB4774A65B308471) org1(BB4774A65B308471) department1(BB4774A65B308471)], MSP: [Org1MSP]
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-05-22 09:28:40.217 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 4de8 0xc0034b0b50 principal evaluation fails
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-05-22 09:28:40.217 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 4de9 0xc0034b0b50 signed by 1 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-05-22 09:28:40.217 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 4dea 0xc0034b0b50 processing identity 0 - &{Org1MSP 1635f57eaf46859c66528c1528475f51feac49aa83b3393c0bdc35e50e046f39}
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-05-22 09:28:40.217 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 4deb 0xc0034b0b50 identity 0 does not satisfy principal: The identity is not valid under this MSP [Org1MSP]: could not validate identity's OUs: the identity must be a client, a peer, an orderer or an admin identity to be valid, not a combination of them. OUs: [member(BB4774A65B308471) org1(BB4774A65B308471) department1(BB4774A65B308471)], MSP: [Org1MSP]
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-05-22 09:28:40.217 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 4dec 0xc0034b0b50 principal evaluation fails
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-05-22 09:28:40.217 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 4ded 0xc0034b0b50 signed by 2 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-05-22 09:28:40.217 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 4dee 0xc0034b0b50 processing identity 0 - &{Org1MSP 1635f57eaf46859c66528c1528475f51feac49aa83b3393c0bdc35e50e046f39}
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-05-22 09:28:40.217 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 4def 0xc0034b0b50 identity 0 does not satisfy principal: could not validate identity's OUs: the identity must be a client, a peer, an orderer or an admin identity to be valid, not a combination of them. OUs: [member(BB4774A65B308471) org1(BB4774A65B308471) department1(BB4774A65B308471)], MSP: [Org1MSP]
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-05-22 09:28:40.217 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 4df0 0xc0034b0b50 principal evaluation fails
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-05-22 09:28:40.217 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 4df1 0xc0034b0b50 gate 1590139720217279088 evaluation fails
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-05-22 09:28:40.217 UTC [policies] EvaluateSignedData -> DEBU 4df2 Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Application/Org1MSP/Writers
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-05-22 09:28:40.217 UTC [policies] EvaluateSignedData -> DEBU 4df3 == Done Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Application/Org1MSP/Writers
```

```
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-05-22 09:28:40.217 UTC [discovery] processQuery -> WARN 4e0b got query for channel mychannel from 192.168.96.1:40612 but it isn't eligible: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-05-22 09:28:40.217 UTC [discovery] processQuery -> WARN 4e0c got query for channel mychannel from 192.168.96.1:40612 but it isn't eligible: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied
```

Am I missing some configuration which should be enabled for `member` identity to evaluate transactions or is it not possible for `member` identity submitting transaction ? Because `client` identity works smoothly.

Any clarification to my understanding is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In config.yaml file under msp folder of your org you have only client , peer , admin , orderer as OrganizationalUnitIdentifier. If you want **member** also to be an identity in your organisation then for that you have to add

```sh
MemberOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: path/to/ca-cert
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: member
```

in your config.yaml file.

for more information about identity : https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/msp.html#identity-classification

Comment: Thanks for responding, I did try the same but no luck.